# Integration Service Catalog and Linked server

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, linked-server

I have SSIS packages in SSIS catalog on SQL Server, Serv1. The packages, while executing, establish connection to SQL Server, Serv2. And they fail while acquiring connection.

I know a little bit about linked server that is to run query from one server on another the latter one has to be a linked server to former one. The above scenatrio looks the same but i didn't find any information related to it. Do i have to add Serv2 as Linked Server for Serv1?

Answer (score 0):

No. Linked server scenario is used when you need to access DB from the outer server inside SQL query run on local server.
SSIS packages are built with goal that it access some DB server, possibly a remote one, fetch data from it, transform and store results somewhere - in files, DB etc. Accessing a remote SQL DB is a normal scenario.
Moreover, using Linked server in SSIS package is a bad practice. You move control of DB access from SSIS catalogue to DB server, in case of any problems - it is more difficult to trace and investigate.

In your case - SSIS packages in SSIS catalogue - check in package execution log which connection string is used to connect to the remote server. Is it an integrated authentication? Does the account under which SSIS package is executed have an access to the DB? If using SQL auth - are login and password valid?